# Use supercomputer to run a program

Tags: network-interface, system-programming

I wrote a c++ program using some libraries called linbox, givaro, gmp.
Now because my computer is to slow I want to run my program on a supercomputer.

I am not very familiar with networks and my programming skills are not very high. I managed to upload the data that the program uses and the c++ program itself. But of course the supercomputer has not the libraries I need and so I can not compile/link.

Can you tell me how can I proceed to get my program working or can you give me a good reference where I can learn to run c++ programs on supercomputers?

I am using the supercomputer  [brutuswiki.ethz.ch/brutus/Getting_started_with_Euler](http://brutuswiki.ethz.ch/brutus/Getting_started_with_Euler)

Comment: Or at least can you give me a good reference where I can learn to run c++ programs on supercomputers.

Comment: do you have more details about your supercomputer ? what OS/scheduler is it running ? can you package your app in a container and run it on the supercomputer ?

Comment: I found a short guide mor the supercomputer I want to use http://brutuswiki.ethz.ch/brutus/Getting_started_with_Euler

Comment: I understand that there are modules that I am able to use but what should I do if the programs I need are not available there?

Comment: Please add the last comment as an update to your question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to U&L.

Comment: Actually it helped me a lot understanding static and dynamic linkers. But I agree it is not directly related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the hpc doesn't contain required libs, you have 2 options:

1. Ask the admins to install the required libs
2. Build a static executable, which contains all the libs.

If possible to go with option (2), just compile it on your machine, then upload to the hpc and run as is.

I suspect unless you have mpi/pgas as part of your code, that the performance gain would not be great - supercomputers for the most part are a cluster of "ordinary" nodes, with fast interconnects.

Being able to run concurrently is what makes an app take advantage of hpc.